# How to stop WordPress returning 404 on paginated pages after using add_rewrite_rule()?

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules

I'm using `add_rewrite_rule()` to create a custom endpoint:

- example.com/author/username/my-endpoint

I need pagination on this page because I'm displaying a list of users using `WP_User_Query`. When I visit these URLs I see the users I should be seeing so everything appears to be working:

- example.com/author/username/my-endpoint/
- example.com/author/username/my-endpoint/page/2/
- example.com/author/username/my-endpoint/page/3/ etc

**The problem:** when I visit the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools when viewing the paginated pages (my-endpoint/page/2/ and my-endpoint/page/3/ etc), it tells me WordPress is returning a 404.

Here's the full code I'm using:

```
// Add query var.
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my-endpoint';
    return $vars;
} );
// Add rewrite rules.
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^author/([^/]+)/my-endpoint/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&my-endpoint=1&paged=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^author/([^/]+)/my-endpoint/?$', 
    'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&my-endpoint=1', 
    'top'
);
// Template display
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'my-endpoint', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        return trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'my-endpoint.php';
    }
    return $template;
} );
// The user query in my my-endpoint.php template.
$page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
$args = array(
    'count_total' => true,
    'include'     => $ids,
    'number'      => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'offset'      => ( $page - 1 ) * get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'orderby'     => 'include',
    'paged'       => $page
);
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

Why is WordPress returning a 404 on paginated pages?

- example.com/author/username/my-endpoint/page/2/
- example.com/author/username/my-endpoint/page/3/ etc

**Update**

I tried using my own query var as suggested in the answer below but I continue to see the 404:

```
// Add query var.
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'my-endpoint';
    $vars[] = 'userpaged';
    return $vars;
} );
// Add rewrite rules.
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^author/([^/]+)/my-endpoint/userpaged/([0-9]+)/?$',
    'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&my-endpoint=1&userpaged=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a 404 because you use the wordpress `paged` query var, and therefor wordpress tries to locate in the main query that page for that user, and if the user is not an author, or just havn't published anything, there will be no posts for that page and wordpress will set the headers to 404.

Easy solution, make additional query var for your own paging.

Thinking a little more deeply into it... you will probably want to use the `status_header`, called from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/status_header/ in any case to modify the status header being sent, as there might be cases in which the user pagination gives empty results while the main loop will find something.

The tricky part is to know what should be the status way before any output is done, therefor waiting to get to template usage is too late and needs to be done when the main query is being "computed", so probably at `pre_get_posts` filter, even you do not need to change anything in the main query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using my own query var (see my update above) but I continue to see the 404.

Comment: hmm (useful but) wrong filter. will a mend the answer in a sec

Comment: as for why you still got a 404, with using a new paging var, it might be because the user was not an author, or have no associated posts

Comment: None of my users returned by the query have posts. That could explain the 404 because the main query is finding no 2nd, 3rd, 4th page etc.

Comment: The main query is for posts and my custom query (which I need pagination for) is for users. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: yeh, but wordpress always runs the main query, so the only option I guess is to fully avoid it, but you can't really do that before parsing the URL. It actually brings also the question of is there any point in using the template hierarchy, after all, if there is no post using `wp_head` and `wp_footer` might give you surprising result. Seems to me that the best thing is to redesign your DB, make a new "virtual user" cpt, and add a "post" in it for each user. This will greatly simplify everything you do as you will be able you just use the loops and template hierarchy.

Comment: With reference to a solution, I'm wondering if adjusting the number of found posts in the main query to the number of users found by my custom query would work? I notice there's a found_posts filter.

Comment: Using the `found_posts` filter to fool the main query into thinking there was more posts didn't work. How else can I fool the main query? I think the solution would be to get the number of posts found by the main query to match the number of users returned by my custom user query.

Comment: maybe you missed my previous comment, I suggest you change your approch and use a CPT

Comment: I don't think making each user have a post is the solution. In my example links above, the main query is for user `username`. Pagination will work if the number of posts by that user `===` the number of users returned by my custom user query. Right now, `username` has 1 post, hence why page/2/ and page/3/ etc return 404.

Comment: in the end wordpress is "post" oriented, it will probably be easier if you map users into post instead of fighting the system on every step. just my 2 cents

Comment: Thanks Mark I'll keep that idea in mind in case I can't get this working